# How To Convert A List to A Tree in Python?

Tags: python, list, tree, nested

How i can represent a tree from a nested list?

```
L = [['bike', '2 * wheel+1* frame'], ['wheel', '1*rim+1*spoke+1*hub'], ['rim', 60],['spoke', 120]

Tree = ['bike', 2, ['wheel', 1, ['rim', 60], 1, ['spoke', 120], 1, ['hub', 2]]
```

Explanation :

In this example bike is made from 2 wheels and 1 frames,
                 wheel is made from 1 rim,1spoke and 1 hub
                 ['rim', 60] means that rim's price is 60.

I could not understand how to convert the list to tree.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, stack traces, compiler errors - whatever is applicable). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive.

Comment: I fail to see the problem. You **already have** a tree, it's represented with nested lists.

Comment: Does the order of the tree matter?

Comment: @StoryTeller: The poster wants a function such that `f(L) == Tree`

Comment: Thanks for your advice but if i do not know how to begin the code, how i can do the things you ask for :) I'm at a beginner level in Python, its my 1st semester in Computer Science. Thanks again..

Comment: Yes, the order matters. Tree[0] should be the datum and the main structure that includes the others(bike is the main structure and it's constructed from the wheel and frames.)

Comment: @Ezgi Akçora: Perhaps this problem is too advanced for you to tackle right now.

Comment: I mean does the spoke need to be listed after the rim? Does `'1*rim+1*spoke+1*hub'` imply order, or could that mean `spoke, hub, rim` without consequence?

Comment: @martineau, but i have to understand it for my homework, unfortunatelly :(

Comment: @eric No, it does not matter. But the input is changing, bike is just an example and by the way, the children number can be more than 2.

Comment: Yes, I worked that out from the example I just gave, `'1*rim+1*spoke+1*hub'`

Comment: so i guess i should write it recursively?

Comment: and define the parts by using helper functions?

Answer (score 2):

Here're the steps I'd take:

1. Write a function such that `f('2 * wheel+1* frame') == {'wheel': 2, 'frame': 1}`
2. Run that function on the entire list to generate

   ```
   [
       ('bike', {'wheel': 2, 'frame': 1}),
       ('wheel', {'rim': 1, 'spoke': 1, 'hub': 1}),
       ('rim', 60)
   ]
   ```
3. Iterate over this list, and change it to:

   ```
   [
       ('bike', {
           ('wheel', {
               ('rim', 60): 1,
               ('spoke', ...): 1,
               ('hub', ...): 1
           }): 2,
           ('frame', ...): 1
       })            
   ]
   ```

   By replacing `'wheel'` with `('wheel', {'rim': 1, 'spoke': 1, 'hub': 1})` etc, recursively
4. Munge this tree format into the desired output

Comment: I am trying to begin like that :

        def construct(L):
            if type(L[0][1]) == int or float:
               return L[0][1] + construct(L[1:])
            else:
               (L[0][1]).split('+')
               (L[0][1][0]).split('*')
               return (L[0][1][0][0]) + construct(L[0][1][0][1])


but the error is 'index out of range'. I guess they're about split functons?

Comment: @EzgiAkçora Don't mix your string parsing in with your recursion. Write a completely separate function, as I described in step 1