# remove blank characters from a string in python

Tags: python

I have nested lists.in this lists, every nested list contains two component and each component may contain blank (' ') character.I wanted to delete and wrote a piece of code but couldn't make it work.How can i overcome this problem ?

the nested List of List is :

```
[['bike', '2 * wheel+1* frame'], ['wheel', '1  * rim + 1* spoke +1 *hub'], ['rim', 60], ['spoke', 120], ['hub', '2*gear+1*axle'], ['gear', 25], ['axle', '5*bolt+7*nut'],['bolt',0.1], ['nut', 0.15],['frame', '1*rearframe+ 1*frontframe'],['rearframe', 175],['frontframe', '1*fork+2*handle'], ['fork', 22.5],['handle', 10.0]]
```

As seen there are some blanks in some strings.

The python code i wrote :

```
def blanks(des):
    a = 0
    while a < len(des): 
        if type(des[0][1]) == str: 
            des[0][0] = des[0][0].replace(' ','')
        if type(des[0][1]) == str:
            des[0][1] = des[0][1].replace(' ','')
        a += 1

    return des
```

Comment: use isinstance() instead of type(..) == str

Comment: Format your example data properly and write exactly what you want.

Comment: Neither code nor data nor question make much sense.

Comment: It seems that he just wants to get rid of all spaces in Strings present in his nested list. so `'2 * wheel+1* frame'` becomes `'2*wheel+1*frame'`, and so on.

Comment: Is the nesting level fixed or variable ?

Comment: I am not guessing what OP thinks what this code must do. SO is not the guess-my-code game.

Comment: sanchit, you are true about expected result, AshRj, there is no fixed list level. @CRUSADER i excuse about my post but others understood.thanks for your effort.

Comment: There, @kycklysf I made a very generic solution that removes spaces from nested lists. and yes CRUSADER you are correct, the guessing game is generally bad.

Answer (score 1):

Use a `for` loop instead.

```
def blanks(lis):
    for i, _ in enumerate(lis):
        for j in range(2):
            if isinstance(lis[i][j], str):
                lis[i][j] = lis[i][j].replace(' ', '')
    return lis
```

A list comprehension would work as well.

```
def blanks(lis):
    return [i.replace(' ', '') if isinstance(i, str) else i for a in lis for i in a]
```

Or just without the function definition:

```
lis = [[i.replace(' ', '') if isinstance(i, str) else i for i in a] for a in lis]
```

I think this should do what you want. If however, your nested list has an inconsistent depth, you would be better off using a generator function.

```
def blanks(lis):
    for i, el in enumerate(lis):
        if isinstance(el, list):
            blanks(el)
        elif isinstance(el, str):
            yield el.replace(' ', '')
        else:
            yield el
```

See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2158532/1907098) for more information on the last piece of code.

Answer (score 0):

This would be one way to do:

```
map(lambda x:map(lambda y:y.replace(' ','') if isinstance(y,str) else y,x),a)
```

where `a` is the input list which you pass on.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so since there isn't a limit or any fixed parameters you will have to use a little bit of recursion to solve your problem.

```
def trimSpaces(list):
  for i in range(0,len(list)):
    if type(list[i]) == str:
      list[i] = list[i].replace(' ','')
    elif type(list[i]) == type([]):
      list[i] = trimSpaces(list[i])
    else:
      continue
  return list
```

Comment: For some reason `type(list[i]) == list` didn't work for me. Dunno, but this works!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
def removeBlanks(input):

  if type(input) is list:
    ret=[]
    for i in input:
      ret.append(removeBlanks(i))
  else:
    ret=input.replace(" ", "")

  return ret
```

Answer (score 0):

In python, you usually want to follow [EAFP](http://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-eafp) and catch exceptions instead of prevalidiating input with `isinstance`:

```
def no_blanks(s):
    try:
        return s.replace(' ', '')
    except AttributeError:
        return s

ls = [['bike', '2 * wheel+1* frame'], ['wheel', '1  * rim + 1* spoke +1 *hub'], ['rim', 60], ['spoke', 120], ['hub', '2*gear+1*axle'], ['gear', 25], ['axle', '5*bolt+7*nut'],['bolt',0.1], ['nut', 0.15],['frame', '1*rearframe+ 1*frontframe'],['rearframe', 175],['frontframe', '1*fork+2*handle'], ['fork', 22.5],['handle', 10.0]]

new_ls = [[no_blanks(a), no_blanks(b)] for a, b in ls]
```

Also looking at your list closely it seems to me that `dict` would be perhaps a better choice for your data.

Comment: @kycklysf: just out of interest, are you building something similar to http://stackoverflow.com/q/14273581/989121 ?

Comment: @kycklysf: in this case I'd suggest using nested dictionaries instead of strings, like `{'bike': {'wheel':2, 'frame':1}, 'wheel': {'rim':1` etc

Comment: actually i want to do http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14101633/how-to-convert-a-list-to-a-tree-in-python?rq=1 how an algorithm would you suggest ?

Comment: @kycklysf: you'd better ask a new question about that (but try something on your own first).

Comment: by my question i get an blank-removed nested lists, then my purpose is  to convert a list to a tree as same as the link above.

Comment: thank you, of course, before posting i will put my effort on it.